# How to generate Random Numeric String having 6 digits in Gatling?

Tags: scala, gatling

I am new to  Gatling and Scala Environment.

How to generate a Random Numeric String having 6 digits, in Gatling?

For example, I need to feed "123456" for an attribute in Gatling.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: In the below code I was able to filter letters from the alphanumeric string. What is the code to filter numbers from that?                                                                                                                     val username = Iterator.continually(Map("username" -> (Random. alphanumeric.filter(_.isLetter).take (8).mkString.toLowerCase())))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with what you've got and make the following change...

```
...filter(_.isDigit).take(6).mkString
```

...but I'd be more inclined toward the following.

```
(Random.nextInt(900000)+100000).toString
```

Note: For the 1st proposed solution, leading zeros are possible, `"010203"` for example. That's not the case for the 2nd. Not sure which is preferred.

---

Scala 2.13.x option:

```
util.Random.between(100000, 1000000)
//minimum (inclusive)--^      ^--maximum (exclusive)
```

Comment: This (second snippet) doesn't work right for small numbers (there will be a dot in the output .,,. or just `0`t). Something like this maybe?
(Random.nextInt(899999) + 100000).toString`

Comment: @Dima; Yeah, _*sigh*_, I was a bit rushed in posting the 2nd option. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Really sorry for the late reply.

Comment: "(Random.nextInt(899999)+100000).toString" - This worked for me. Thanks a lot.